# How to prevent attach shell in docker node alpine image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

When I write `docker exec -it mycontainer sh`, I can connect docker container and see everything inside it. I want to prevent user from attaching shell. How can I do it?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.12-alpine

RUN usermod --shell /usr/sbin/logoutd root

WORKDIR /app


COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

I tried to change shell for root user and prevent attach shell by this line: `RUN usermod --shell /usr/sbin/logoutd root`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do it?

You can't.

You can write a docker [access authorization plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_authorization/) that will disable `docker exec`.

Often people remove everything and all executables except those needed, essentially preventing to execute anything. Still, `docker cp` will work. And then, `docker save` will still work and allows getting all files.